# Regex to remove periods in acronyms?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove periods in acronyms from a string of text, but I also want o leave regular periods (at the end of a sentence for example) in tact.

So the following sentence:

```
"The C.I.A. is a department in the U.S. Government."
```

Should become

```
"The CIA is a department in the US Government."
```

Is there a clean way to do this using Python? So far I have a two step process:

```
words = "The C.I.A. is a department in the U.S. Government."
words = re.sub(r'([A-Z].[A-Z.]*)\.', r'\1', words)
print words
# The C.I.A is a department in the U.S Government.    
words = re.sub(r'\.([A-Z])', r'\1', words)
print words
# The CIA is a department in the US Government.
```

Comment: Could there be any single-letter-acronyms?

Comment: What about `etc.`? If you only care about uppercase single letters followed with a dot, you may use `re.sub(r'\b([A-Z])\.', r'\1', words)`, but this is not a general solution.

Comment: It comes down to the question *"how do you know something is an ancronym and not a sentence?"* Once you have an answer to that, then you can start building a regex.

Comment: What are the exact rules of the matching? Is this merely a small sample of what you are really trying to achieve? Are you dealing with several blocks of text where ultimately you are just trying to remove dots from all things that qualify as an acronym?

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that users won't enter a single letter acronym, and if they do, they probably won't put a period. `"etc."` is an abbreviation, and abbreviations are too complex for this initial question.

Comment: @mgoldwasser, what is an example of a single letter  acronym?

Comment: So you're trying to de-New-Yorkify some prose? That is, remove the crazy periods that The New Yorker and the NYT (or N.Y.T. they would call it) insist on putting in acronyms and initialisms? You'll need more tests, for example: `The C.I.A. is a department in the U.S. Government. That is to say, the U.S. govt. has a dept. called the C.I.A. The Man From U.N.C.L.E. does not work there, he works for U.N.C.L.E. Tricky for an R.E.: "U.N.C.L.E." *is* properly spelled with the periods, both in N.Y. and elsewhere. Of course Y.M.M.V. (Unless you're the N.Y.T.) So says I.`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably this?

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!\w)([A-Z])\.', r'\1', s)
'The CIA is a department in the US Government.'
```

Replace single dots that are preceded by an uppercase single letter provided the single letter is not immediately preceded by anything in the `\w` character set.  The later criterion is enforced by the *negative lookbehind assertion* - `(?<!\w)`.

Comment: Curious to know if OP is still looking to handle things like `etc.`. Otherwise, this works well.

Comment: You might want to also explain the code. Actually it also fails for `I.` in a sentence.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah yes. Added some explanation. Not sure if `I.` will count as an acronym, maybe abbreviation.

Comment: Looks fine but will fail for any single capital letter followed by a period which is valid in a lot of English sentences. As in it would remove the valid punctuation to end the sentence

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That's true. I think a possible fix will be to exclude using a `lambda` the first person preposition when it's followed by a `.`, if of course that is the only case your example can appear in the English language. And OP also needs to clarify on the previous cases.

Comment: Yes, I agree on the clarification, unless the OP has set finite set of possible inputs  then a a general solution would be a lot more complex .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm currently searching to see if NLTK already has a way to handle this, but nothing so far.

Comment: I cannot even find a single letter acronym, I  am beginning to think it might be a unicorn https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKWmFWRVLlU

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I found a unicorn and luckily in a Python mailing list :)) *The most obvious complication is treatment of 
dotted and dotless **I.***, from [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2012-January/013293.html)

Comment: Please explain to me, why replace it by "\1" instead of "\2"?